# Problem with logical OR

Tags: javascript

What's wrong with this code:

```
if (Gender != "M" || Gender != "F")
{
    alert("Please enter gender." + Gender);
    document.getElementById("gender").focus();
    return false;                               
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably mean `and` instead of `or`:

```
if (Gender != "M" && Gender != "F")
```

Comment: I am using in a DropDown, so I mean OR.

Comment: Well, if you use an OR then that statement will always return true. Why have the statement at all?

Comment: Kai is right. Your test will always be true because the Gender != "F" part is true if the user chooses Gender = M.

Comment: Problem is with the logic, not the logical OR ;)

Answer (score 6):

Read it as:

```
if (gender is not male OR gender is not female)
{
  //
}
```

Lets say gender is male: since gender is not female, `if` evaluates to `true`.

Now if the gender is female: since it is not male, `if` again evaluates to `true`.

You meant to say if gender is neither male nor not female, right? As other people suggested, you have to use AND here.

```
if (gender is not male AND gender is not female)

//which is
if (Gender != "M" && Gender != "F")
```

Answer (score 5):

The condition will always be true because if `Gender == 'M'` then it will be `!= 'F'` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a dropdownlist, we assume you have 3 values eg: an empty string, "M" and "F".

In that case I would check for the empty string to simplify logic issues:

```
if (Gender == "")
{
  alert("Please enter gender." + Gender);
  document.getElementById("gender").focus();    
  return false;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

**Your conditional, as written, is always true**

If Gender is "M", then  (Gender != "F") is true.

If Gender is "F", then  (Gender != "M") is true.

Therefore, if Gender is either "M" or "F", then (Gender != "M" || Gender != "F") is true, meaning that your code block will *always* execute.

@Kai is right - you want logical *and*. In English, you want to ask:

If gender is not M and gender is not F, then ask the user for gender.

**Edit:** Corrected my reversed results.

Comment: Unless the post has been edited, I believe you mean true, not false.

Comment: ...except that the condition is always *true*. ;-)

Comment: @Lord: I edited since code lines were not formatted properly.

Comment: @LordTorgamus and @dtsazza - Thanks for catching that before the downvotes came. I corrected my mistake. That's what I get for rushing an answer.